# How to increment iterator while implementing set as dynamic vector

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, iterator

I am trying to implement set as dynamic vector, but I don't know how to increment my iterator.

My code:

```
#pragma once

class node
{
public:
    elem e;

    node(){}
    node(elem e):e(e){};
    node(const node<elem>& n)
    {
        this->e=n->e;

    }
};




class iteratorr
{
public:

    node<elem>* current;

    iteratorr():current(NULL){};
    iteratorr(Node<elem>* c):current(c){};
    iteratorr(const Iterator<elem>& it)
    {
        this->current=it.current;
    }


    iteratorr<elem>& operator++()
    {

    }
    elem elem(){return current->e;}
};
```

Both classes are template typename elem. For some reason I can't write it in the code.
If I would add a pointer to a next node in class node, that would become a linked list I guess. How could I increment my iterator?

Comment: If it's a dynamic vector, then `current++;`...?

Comment: Current is a node, so I would need to write a function in node which does the increment of a node, and pretty much that was my problem from the start.

Comment: Current is a pointer to a node, and don't you want it to point to the next node after it the one it currently points to? (Assuming "dynamic vector" means they're all in adjacent memory locations)

Comment: You don't need "nodes". They don't add anything to elements.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. Now I realize what you wanted to say. I will try and come back with the result.